# MVC3 null Querystring Returned To Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

It seems that once I define my Form like -->
using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))

The additional parameters being passed are now null.

MyController/Create/4?pid=61&status=Initiated

**pid** and **status** returns null although the parameters are being passed as above.
What is causing these querystring parameters to be be null?

Using Request["myparameter"] or simply getting value from action method parameter returns null.

Comment: Can you show your View and Controller code and then we can see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyController", new { pid = Request.QueryString["pid"] },   FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is very weird as the following works perfectly fine for me:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string pid, string foo)
    {
        // the pid and foo parameters are correctly assigned here
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { pid = "63" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("foo", "some value")
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: HERE IS MY Action Method------->
public ActionResult Create(WizardViewModel wizardViewModel, int id, int? pid, string SavedJsonRoles, string SavedJsonMetrics, string Status, bool NOVALIDATION) {

Comment: My hidden values e.g. SavedJsonMetircs are returned with no problem.

Comment: @Nate, yes this should also work with view models as action arguments. Just make sure that you are passing the other values (pid, status) as query string parameters in the request. See my example of how to use Html.BeginForm to achieve this (I have hardcoded the `pid` value but you could fetch it from the current Request as well if it is present: `new { pid = Request["pid"] })`.

Comment: The strange thing is that the parameters get passed in if I change my using statement to -->  using (Html.BeginForm()) {}

Comment: @Nate, yes, that's because when you use the `Html.BeginForm()` helper without specifying any argument it simply uses the current url as action. So if there were argument in it they are automatically copied. If you use some of the other overloads you need to specify them manually.